# cv2.circle() not showing

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have the following code that's working, except the draw circle on the provided image. I tried the setMouseCallback example on [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d5b/tutorial_py_mouse_handling.html#gsc.tab=0), which is working but I'm afraid I have implemented it wrong in my own code.

```
import numpy as np
import urllib.request as ur
import cv2

params = np.zeros([1, 2])  # init params
s_img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)


def clicked_corners(camera, user, pw):
    """
    Function to write the clicked corners (ij) to a camera object.
    Image is provided by a valid url to a snapshot of camera,
    usually in the form of http://xxx.xxx.x.x/snapshot/view0.jpg
    :param camera: Camera object
    :param user: username to authorize access to URL if set
    :param pw: password to authorize access to URL if set
    """
    window_name = 'img'
    ... # define url, not important to the question
    global params, s_img

    ... # handle authentication, not important to the question

    ... #open url
    img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)  # decode array to an image
    s_img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
    cv2.startWindowThread()

    cv2.imshow(window_name, s_img)
    print('Click corners to determine the field')
    cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, on_mouse, params) # <-- setting callback for mouseclicks
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF  # adding a keylistener

    if k == 27:
        ... # destroy window

    clicked_points = params

    return clicked_points


def on_mouse(event, x, y, flag, param):
    global params
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ... do some operation
        cv2.circle(s_img, (x, y), 100, (255, 0, 0), -1) # **draw circle this part is not working properly**

    ... return something
```

I have edited the code to highlight the important parts to the questions, and where I assume it's not going as it should be.

Comment: maybe setting callback cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, on_mouse, params) before imshow work?

Comment: Your pasted code contains lots of stuff that doesn't seem relevant to the question. To make it possible for others to reproduce your problem, you should make more effort to isolate where the problem is before posting. Read this guide [mcve]

Comment: @orkan Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thank you for the suggestion. I will edit it appropriately.

Comment: Try adding a `cv2.waitKey(1)` after you draw the circle

Comment: @Miki Tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed. Essentially what I did was adding a call to imshow() to show the updated version of the image with circle drawn. This corrected version works without any glitches, the window_name makes sure that existing window is used to display the updated image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

params = np.zeros([1, 2])  # init params
s_img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
window_name = 'img'

def main():
    global s_img
    img = np.ones([512, 512, 3]) * 255
    s_img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cv2.imshow(window_name, s_img)

    print ('Click corners to determine the field')
    cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, on_mouse, None)

    while True:
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

        if k == 27:
            break # destroy window


def on_mouse(event, x, y, flag, param):
    global s_img
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print ('here')
        cv2.circle(s_img, (x, y), 100, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.imshow(window_name, s_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @ALGOholic, this seems to be working for me. Thank you very much. Particularly, I see you've put an 'cv2.imshow()' right after the drawing of the circle in 'on_mouse()', which seems to be why I was having this problem. How did you find it? Anyway, welcome to SO and thank you for your useful answer!

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that coupling between image update and window update was missing altogether. I didn't expect the window to be tracking state of the image intelligently - it's rarely the case in UI frameworks.